# Using Google Protocol Buffers with Java NIO?

Tags: java, nio, protocol-buffers

I'm currently playing around with `java.nio`, which I haven't been using for a long time. I use [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for serialization and for communication with other parts of my system. Now I can't figure out if/how it is possible to get use protobuffers with `java.nio` classes.

I can't imagine that Google is using only "one thread per connection" with networked protocol buffers. Could anyone give me a pointer on how to integrate the two?

Thanks in advance!
Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest [Netty](http://jboss.org/netty), specifically this [example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/localtime/package-summary.html) that is Netty using ProtoBufs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I wanted to avoid adding another library, but I'll for sure have a look at Netty.